# Postgres configuration for use in embedded?

Tags: postgresql

I have the same 5000 key/value pairs being read/written continuously (every 150ms or so) on a Debian system equivalent to a Raspberry Pi 3.

I don't care about persisting this data, it's recreated whenever my application server is launched.

Initially I used SQLite for this, using an in-memory table. However, now I want to access the data from multiple processes (using a tmpfs didn't work out great) and even from a remote client, as well as add an HTTP API, use LISTEN/NOTIFY for change notifications, so I'd like to switch to PG which is more appropriate for these.

Given these circumstances:

- small dataset that fits in RAM
- no need for persistence
- low power PC
- running 24/7 forever
- don't want to thrash the flash storage

...what would be a good approach to configuring PG?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729690/postgresql-equivalent-of-mysql-memory-tables) 10yo question and the last update was 5 years ago saying to use a 3rd party extension, which I'm not too excited about.

Comment: Have you tried the default configuration and tested your application? If that hasn't worked well for you, try https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/ and it'll give you configuration that can help you.

Comment: For a small in-memory available as a server, I would use [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)). As I vaguely recall it offers a Postgres emulation mode so Postgres-related tools can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You should create few indexes apart from the primary keys and keep the `fillfactor` of all your tables low, perhaps around 50. That should get you [HOT updates](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/hot-updates-in-postgresql-for-better-performance/), which will reduce the need for `VACUUM` and the amount of data written.

You may want to reduce `shared_buffers` to conserve memory, but keep it big enough to contain the database.

Set `synchronous_commit` to `off` to have less disk I/O. If you are ready to ditch the database after an unclean shutdown or system crash, you can set `fsync = off`, but then you have to remove the cluster after each crash. If you take it that far, you could reduce the write load further by using unlogged tables.

Set `checkpoint_timeout` high for fewer writes.